# Drop row in dataframe based on condition in column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rows

I have a dataframe that looks as follows

```
                                       class                 number  2015                                   0             0     0   
ret                                    Real Estate             1     0   
ret                                          empty             2     0   
ret                                         Equity             3     0   
ret                                 Participations             4     0   
ret                                          empty             5     0   
ret                                 Private Equity             6     0   
ret                                     Hedge Fund             7     0   
ret                                     High Yield             8     0   
ret              Loan, Multitranchen, FSB, FSS_FSB             9     0   
ret                                          empty            10     0   
ret                                   Loan GR, FSB            11     0   
ret                                          empty            12     0   
ret                                Corporate Bonds            13     0
```

I would like to delete all the rows for which the value in column "class" is "empty". The following code only returns the dataframe with NA values.

```
df[df[["class"]] != "empty"]
```

Can anyone help me out with that?

Comment: `df[df["class"] != "empty"]`? `df[['class']]` returns a data frame.